# Как отключить срабатывание update у save() при цикле

Tags: yii2

Собствено вот сам код

```
 $model = new Image();
 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    foreach($files->files as $file){
        $years=date('Y');
                $mounts=date('m');
                $model->path = $path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/';
                $model->name = $files_to;
                $model->title_alt=$altNames." ".$count;
                $model->save();
                 $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/image/') . $path . '/' . $years . '/' . $mounts . '/' . $files_to);
                 }
}
```

вот так в дебагере получается

```
INSERT INTO `fl_image` (`title_alt`, `for_home`, `id_film`, `path`, `name`) VALUES ('Тарзан. Легенда 0', 0, 1, 'film/2016/07/', '12089457.jpg')
UPDATE `fl_image` SET `title_alt`='Тарзан. Легенда 1', `name`='Space-Desktop.jpg' WHERE `id`=2180
UPDATE `fl_image` SET `title_alt`='Тарзан. Легенда 2', `name`='xJtqzdQr7RE.jpg' WHERE `id`=2180
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам стоит внести создание нового объекта *$model* в цикл как-то так:

```
foreach ($files->files as $file) {
    $model = new Image();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
          $years = date('Y');
          $mounts = date('m');
          $model->path = $path.'/'.$years.'/'.$mounts.'/';
          $model->name = $files_to;
          $model->title_alt = $altNames." ".$count;
          $model->save();
          $file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/image/') . $path . '/' . $years . '/' . $mounts . '/' . $files_to);
    }
}
```

Comment: А как мне получить files->files которая этой формой отправляются ?

Comment: @Sergalas Посмотрите тут - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-file-upload.md